# how to configure fiddler to use infopath to customize forms in sharepoint to avoid the "following URL is not valid" error in offline mode

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath-forms-services

I installed vmware virtual machine on my laptop to run SharePoint server 2013, then I installed  win server 2012 and sharepoint server on the virtual machine, now when i'm gonna to use infopath to customize forms and publishing them back in sharepoint i have following error:
"the following url is not valid"
I create my own root site collection
and added verbs like PUT an et.al to IIS But still I have this error when I'm not connected to the Internet. 
The point is that when I'm connected to the Internet, this error no longer exists.
By searching the internet I found that I should use fiddler,
I downloaded and installed Fiddler4 on my laptop. but when I run it in disconnected internet mode the error still exist.
I have installed windows 8.1 on my laptop and i try the win8 confige button to check all icons, But it still does not work , So, how can I use Fiddler now..... I'm waiting for your answers.........

Comment: Fiddler is used for analyzing traffic from and to your computer. On its own it won't solve any problems. It is used to find what the problem is.

Comment: thank you teylyn, my question is exactly that how can I use fiddler  for this purpose ?

Comment: how can I resolve this error for publishing my forms from info path to SharePoint?